# Outlook: Mark a private flag on sent emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've recently started to automatically add a flag "for follow-up" on every email I send. (I would like to keep track of those emails I sent out).

My problem currently is that my recipients also getting those flags and notifications.

How can I create a flag for this scenario that will be private?

Thanks
Ariel

EDIT: I'm adding the flag via a rule, so I need a way to configure it via rules.

Comment: What type of email account is it? Exchange? IMAP? POP?

Comment: Exchange - Office365

Comment: Do you mean the online-version? Not "Outlook 2013" local offline-version? (as stated in the tags)

Comment: It's local Outlook office 2013.

Comment: Not sure if the web app even has the rules configuration UI...

Comment: Strange. Could you give us the steps to make the rule. In the composing the mail do you have the drop-down besides the "Follow-up" with "Flag for Recipients" checked?

Comment: The UI is a bit different, you can choose custom flag and there you can check "Flag for recipients". But in the rule, I couldn't find a way to force it to be unchecked.

Comment: I asked about the way you created the rule because until and including outlook 2010: If you’re in the Rules Wizard and you’re creating a Rule to “fire” after you send each message, the “flag message for follow-up” is for follow-up by you, not the recipient. Is it named differently in outlook 2013?

Comment: "Apply this rule after I send the message
 flag message for Review within 1 day"

Comment: I'll check tomorrow if i can reproduce this on different outlook versions. (And see if it's a bug or a feature:)

Answer (score 2):

In the "Follow Up" pulldown you can check/uncheck "Flag for Recipients" (before sending the mail).
See [here](http://agsci.psu.edu/it/how-to/use-flags-and-reminders-in-outlook) at the bottom of the page
and [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/flag-an-item-for-follow-up-HA010355003.aspx).

---

**About the bug** with sending of the "Follow Up"-flag ("X-Message-Flag" header) in the rules the following:

I tested this with Outlook 2013 (dutch version).

If you use a **SMTP server** to send mail and manually set the "Follow Up" the X-Message-Flag is added **after** the message is sent.
The recipient does **not** get your private "Follow Up" flag.
Only if you set it to "Custom" and check "Flag for Recipient".
This is the correct behavior.

But if you set it as a rule "Apply this rule after I send the message" it **does** send the X-Message-Flag.
This should be considered a **bug**. *(below is a possible solution)*
You can check this if you create a mail and change, while composing, your private "Follow Up" to a different date, you see in your "Sent mail" your own "Follow Up" but also that of your recipient.

I also found another bug:
If you use **IMAP** (and maybe **Exchange** too) and you set the "Follow Up" manually the X-Message-Flag is added before the message is stored and presumably also **before** it's sent.
This way the recipient does get the "Follow Up" flag. 
This is probably due to the fact that the message has to be stored before sending.
But this could also be considered a bug.

And here also (with IMAP) if you set it as a rule it also **does** send the X-Message-Flag.

(b.t.w. With IMAP i only had the option to Flag or not Flag. No options for Tomorrow etc. Probably a limit with IMAP. [See here](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/623).)

**Now for a possible solution (working with Exchange):**

You can strip the "X-Message-Flag" with a "Transport Rule" -> "Remove this header" with Exchange 2007/2010.

- Open Microsoft Exchange Console
- Navigate to: Microsoft Exchange \ Organization Configuration \ Hub Transport \ Transport Rules
- Right Click and select New Transport Rule and name it “Remove X-Message-Flag” click Next
- Keep it on "send to users inside or outside the organization" and click Next
- Choose "Remove header" and as message header write X-Message-Flag and twice click Next

If you have Exchange 2000/2003 you can use a script found on [this page](http://www.msxfaq.de/clients/xmessageflag.htm) (in German).

Now you recipients don't get the "Follow Up" anymore.
Downside is even if you **want** to send a "Follow Up" to your recipient you won't be able to.

**Edit**:
For "Office 365 for enterprises" you can do it too:
According to [this forum](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/17521.aspx) you can add a "Transport rule" for "Office 365 for enterprises".
[See here](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ms.exch.ecp.newtransportrule.aspx).
and choose Modify message properties... [Remove a message header](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ff628741.aspx#ModifyProperties)

Comment: I *think* outlook 2013 is different; it has a built in "follow up flag" quick-click on the send email screen. See [here](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2012/10/24/quicker-replies-in-the-new-outlook.aspx)

Comment: Isn't there a small triangle just to the right of the "Follow up" "quick-click"-button where you can click to change that? Or you can change the ribbon of the "quick response" to include that button.

Comment: I can't test, I have outlook 2010

Comment: I'm adding the flag via a rule. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I added some more information about the bug and a possible solution with the Exchange server.

Comment: Thanks Rik, we are using Office365 in our organization, is it possible to configure the workaround in that case?

Comment: As i know it, Office365 is not an application but a subscription plan. I take it you have the option for the offline "Office 2013"-suite and are using "Outlook 2013" offline and not the "Webmail" variant. What is the option at the server side? Are you using the "Exchange Online hosted email for business" or have your own Exchange on your own server? If you are using the "Online hosted Exchange" i don't know if you can set all these options. You can ask your hosting provider if he can remove the X-Message-Flag headers.

Comment: Just searched a little deeper. According to [this forum](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/158/t/17521.aspx) you can add a "Transport rule" for "Office 365 for enterprises". [See here](http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/ms.exch.ecp.newtransportrule.aspx).